# Local configuration in deployed Clojure apps

Tags: deployment, clojure, configuration

What is the idiomatic way to store and retrieve configuration settings in a deployed Clojure Luminus app?

In the Luminus template on which I base my app, the `profiles.clj` file is used to store the database connection string. However, when I compile the app using `lein uberjar` the profiles.clj settings do not seem to be included in the compiled file. And I would nevertheless not want the database connection to be stored in the compiled file but rather reside in a configuration file on the production server.

Optimally, local configurations should be stored and retrieved in the same manner regardless of whether the app is run in development or production mode. But I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The http://www.luminusweb.net/docs/environment.md#edn_based_configuration page helped me.
`java -Dconf=config.edn -jar app.jar` will start a compiled app with the configurations stored in config.edn.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in using [the environ library](https://github.com/weavejester/environ).  From their README:

---

Let's say you have an application that requires a database connection. Often you'll need three different databases, one for development, one for testing, and one for production.

Lets pull the database connection details from the key :database-url on the environ.core/env map.

```
(require '[environ.core :refer [env]])

(def database-url
  (env :database-url))
```

The value of this key can be set in several different ways. The most common way during development is to use a local profiles.clj file in your project directory. This file contained a map that is merged with the standard project.clj file, but can be kept out of version control and reserved for local development options.

```
{:dev  {:env {:database-url "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/dev"}}
 :test {:env {:database-url "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test"}}}
```

Comment: This is good advice, because the Luminus template uses Environ. http://www.luminusweb.net/docs/environment.md

Comment: Thanks! But I don't quite follow how one would implement a local configuration file using environ library. I such a file I would like to include e.g., SMTP settings, database connection variables, and other misc variables that are specific for the current environment.